# Independence of two random variables $\xi_1,\xi_2$

Tags: probability

Two-dimensional random variable
$
p_{\xi_1\xi_2}(x_1,x_2)=\begin{cases}
\frac 1 {6\pi},& \frac {{x_1}^2} 9+\frac {{x_2}^2} 4 \leqslant 1,\\
0,&\frac {{x_1}^2} 9+\frac {{x_2}^2} 4 > 1.
\end{cases}
$

Are two random variables $\xi_1$ and  $\xi_2$ independent?

I know if they are independent then $p_{\xi_1\xi_2}(x_1,x_2)=p_{\xi_1}(x_1)p_{\xi_2}(x_2)$. But how I can use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the marginal pdfs
$$
p_{\xi_1}(x_1)=\frac{1}{6\pi}\int_{-\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{36-4 x_1^2}}^{\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{36-4 x_1^2}}dx_2=\frac{1}{9\pi} \sqrt{36-4 x_1^2}\qquad -3\leq x_1\leq 3
$$
and
$$
p_{\xi_2}(x_2)=\frac{1}{6\pi}\int_{-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{36-9 x_2^2}}^{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{36-9 x_2^2}}dx_1=\frac{1}{6\pi}\sqrt{36-9 x_2^2}\qquad -2\leq x_2\leq 2\ .
$$
The product of the two does not reproduce $p_{\xi_1,\xi_2}(x_1,x_2)$, so the two variables are not independent.